# Does conda provide a generator to generate a props file which can be included in a Cpp project?

Tags: conda, miniconda

I am trying to install a conda package which actually contains Cpp library. Once I install the package, the Conda here has installed the include and lib files in $env:CONDA_PREFIX\Library\include and $env:CONDA_PREFIX\Library\lib on Windows. One way is to manually include these directories in the Cpp project. However, I would like to have a props file which is generated and can be directly included in the Cpp project.
So far I have not come across any generators for Conda. Any other possible ways I can achieve this?

**Update:**

Currently I am using CFLAGS in my meta.yaml file as below:
package:

```
  name: boost_new_headers
  version: "1.70.0"

source:
  fn: boost_1_70_0.zip
  url: https://github.com/sandybhat16/Boost/raw/main/boost_1_70_0.zip

build:
  number: 0
  script_env:
    - CFLAGS=-Wno-c++11-narrowing

requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - bzip2 1.0.*
    - zlib 1.2.*

  run:
    - python
    - bzip2 1.0.*
    - zlib 1.2.*

about:
  home: http://www.boost.org/
  license: Boost Software License
```

I have now installed this package. How do I use this package's headers and libs in my CPP project?

P.S I do not want to use cmake or gnu make.

Comment: This is rather generic - if you would like more specific help, please give a concrete (reproducible) example. Conda Forge links against its own libraries all the time and much of this is automated through activation scripts that come with their compilers. For example, if you install `compilers` and `libblas`, you can use the flag `-lblas` with the compiler (C++ compiler is defined by environment variable `CXX`). That is, activating the environment will set the variables such that `include` and `lib` are visible to the compiler.

Comment: @merv Thank you for the info. I have updated the question. I am not sure how do I use this package in my Cpp project?